# On the electromagetic decay of a real pseudoscalar

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I am considering the decay of a real pseudoscalar particle with field $\Phi$ interacting with the electromagnetic field with $\mathcal{L}_{int}=f\Phi\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}$ where the metric is (-,+,+,+) and $\epsilon^{0123}=1$. I have achieved to derive the amplitude $\mathcal{M}=8if\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}p_{2\mu}\epsilon_{2\nu}^*p_{3\rho}\epsilon_{3\sigma}^*$ where $\Phi$ with four-momentum $p_1$ decays into two photons, each with momentum $p_2$, $p_3$, and polarization $\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3$, respectively.
From here, I am trying to calculate $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ with summation over all possible polarizations. I know the completeness relation for the photon polarization $\sum \epsilon_i ^* \epsilon_j = \delta_{ij}-\hat{p}_i\hat{p}_j$. However, I have no idea how to invoke this equation to calculate $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ other than considering all the cases whether each index is zero or not. Is there an easier way to approach this calculation, or should I just continue with such "brute-force" method? Thanks in advance.

Edit: When using the completeness relation above, I am assuming the Coulomb gauge: $\epsilon^0=0$.

Comment: The problem may be that you don't have the full set of polarization vectors. You only have two of them due to the gauge invariance. As a result the identity does not apply.

Comment: Can you make use of the [product of two Levi-Civita symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product_2)?